# Function never executes ElseIf Statements

Tags: vba, excel

Working on some VBA for excel and i wrote a user defined function to do some arithmetic based on row number. It seemed to be working at first glance, then I realized that no matter what it always executed as if the first If statement were true and never took the ElseIf's into account. what am I doing wrong?

```
Function redProfit(ByVal myRange As Range) As Long
    Dim rangerow As Range, baseprofit As Long
    Application.Volatile
    baseprofit = 3500000
    With myRange
        If (.Row = 3 Or 11) Then
            redProfit = baseprofit * 0.1
        ElseIf (.Row = 4 Or 10) Then
            redProfit = baseprofit * 0.08
        ElseIf (.Row = 5 Or 9) Then
            redProfit = baseprofit * 0.07
        ElseIf (.Row = 6 Or 8) Then
            redProfit = baseprofit * 0.06
        ElseIf .Row = 7 Then
            redProfit = baseprofit * 0.05

        End If
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: Why has someone down-voted this question? The OP's problem is clearly stated and the appropriate code is included. Surely we all made this mistake in our early days because "Row equals three or eleven" is how we say it in English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot make successive equality tests without repeating the variable.

It needs to be

```
If (.Row = 3 or .Row = 11) Then
...
```

For the moment, your code reads "If .Row equals 3, or 11". 11 is treated separately and evaluated to true.

Comment: Thanks a ton, answer was staring me in the face for the past 2 hours from my googlefoo but didn't actually stop and read character for character what the examples were showing me. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what others have written, this seems like an instance where the Select Case construct might be preferable:

```
Function redProfit(ByVal myRange As Range) As Long
Dim rangerow As Range, baseprofit As Long
Application.Volatile
baseprofit = 3500000

Select Case myRange.Row
    Case 3, 11
        redProfit = baseprofit * 0.1
    Case 4, 10
        redProfit = baseprofit * 0.08
    Case 5, 9
        redProfit = baseprofit * 0.07
    Case 6, 8
        redProfit = baseprofit * 0.06
    Case 7
        redProfit = baseprofit * 0.05
End Select
End Function
```